# Problem with timezones in pymongo/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have this function which parses the dates in my database

```
def parserQuestions():   
    res=db.questionsActual.find({'date_created':{'$type':'string'}})
    for doc in res:
        db.questionsActual.update_one({'_id': doc.get('_id')}, {'$set': { 'date_created': parse(doc.get('date_created'))}})
```

My input format is:

2020-12-11T13:23:58.677-04:00

but when I apply the function, the output is:

2020-12-11T13:23:58.677.000Z

How can I keep the timezone? or even better, can I set my own timezone?

the desired output is:

2020-12-11T13:23:58.677-04:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's BSON `date` type always stores dates as UTC date/times, so you cannot store an offset directly in a BSON `date` field. You can choose to store your offset in a separate field with something like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from dateutil import parser

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

dt = parser.parse('2020-12-11T13:23:58.677-04:00')

db.questionsActual.insert_one({'date': dt, 'offsetSeconds': dt.tzinfo.utcoffset(dt).total_seconds()})

print(db.questionsActual.find_one({}, {'_id': 0}))
```

gives:

```
{'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11, 17, 23, 58, 677000), 'offsetSeconds': -14400.0}
```